# Scoreboard test for player in minecart not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Command block has:

```
scoreboard players tag @a[x=50080,y=63,z=58171,r=12] add InCar {RootVehicle:{Entity:{id:"MinecartRideable"}}}
```

The output in the command block once run shows:

```
[@: The dataTag does not match for (playername)]
```

Despite being in a minecart. I have also tried this with:

"Minecart"

MinecartRideable (no quotes)

Minecart (no quotes)

"Boat"

Boat

And nothing works. Is there a new syntax which has slipped through obvious documentation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: Entity:{"minecraft:minecart"} - not a very well documented update.

Comment: Minecraft never had an official documentation. 1.13 is actually the best documented update ever. The inofficial, but really good documentation is the Minecraft Wiki. If you see an error there, just correct it or tell people about it on the discussion page.

Comment: The entity ID (i.e. when it's placed on a set of tracks) changed for 1.11; your command probably predates that change.  From the wiki: "1.11 16w32a The entity ID is changed from MinecartRideable to minecart."